# Mojolicious: Can't call method "render" on an undefined value

Tags: perl, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

I'm getting this error and cannot understand why this happens. It happens when I jump to another subroutine. Perhaps there is something I need to understand about Mojolicious on why this happens.

Here is the source code of my program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/' => sub { &start_home; };

app->start;

sub start_home {
  my $d = shift;
  my $something = $d->param('something');
  ### Do things with $something.... etc.. etc..
  &go_somewhere_else; ### Go somewhere else
}

sub go_somewhere_else {
 my $c = shift;
 $c->render(text => "Hello World!");
 ### End of program
}
```

I am passing a value on to the renderer and there is a value - Why would it say it is undefined? My understanding is that this only happens if you jump to a subroutine and try to render output.

My operating system is Windows and I am using Strawberry Perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the context object `$c`/`$d` to your second function. The *undefined value* is your `$c` in `go_somewhere_else`, because you call it without a parameter.

Initially, to make it work, do this.

```
sub start_home {
  my $d = shift;
  my $something = $d->param('something');

  go_somewhere_else($d);
}
```

You are now passing the context, which you named `$d` (that's not the conventional name), to the other function, and the warning will go away.

That's because the form `&subname;` without parenthesis `()` makes `@_` (that's the list of arguments to the function) available inside of `go_somewhere_else`, but because you `shift`ed `$d` off, `@_` is now empty, and hence your `$c` inside `go_somewhere_else` is `undef`.

Alternatively, you could also change the `shift` to an assignment with `@_`. But please, **don't do that**!

```
sub start_home {
  my ( $d ) = @_;
  my $something = $d->param('something');

  &go_somewhere_else;
}
```

---

There are more things odd to the point of almost wrong here.

```
get '/' => sub { &start_home; };
```

You are [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) the the `start_home` function, but you are not actually adding another parameter. I explained above why this works. But it's not great. In fact, it's confusing and complicated.

Instead, you should use a code reference for the route.

```
get '/' => \&start_home;
```

Inside of `start_home`, you should call your context `$c` as is the convention. You should also not use the ampersand `&` notation for calling functions. That changes the behavior in a way you most certainly do not want.

```
sub start_home {
  my $c = shift;
  my $something = $c->param('something');

  # ...
  go_somewhere_else($c);
}
```

To learn more about how function calls work in Perl, refer to [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html).

Comment: @Eugen your edit was not correct. The whole idea of that first code block is that `@_` is empty in the function, so there is absolutely no need to pass it on. I explain that in the paragraph below. I rolled back your edit.

Comment: First and second example works differently in this case. If `start_home` get two or more arguments the first example will discard them all but second one will pass through them. Pass through `@_` at first example explicitly shows that difference between examples only at first argument.